# Reference to wmp.dll (\windows\system32\wmp.dll)

Tags: wmp, wmplib

Can I use a reference to wmpLib.ddl / wmp.dll (\windows\system32\wmp.dll) in a commercial application?

I am using [Visual Studio 2008 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) edition. I have to deliver that DLL.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Darins reply: I don't think that you can simply deploy `wmp.dll` with your product (I'm guessing you're thinking about doing that from the last sentence "I have to deliver that dll.")!

You will have to create an installer that checks whether the correct version of the DLL is present on the target system and have the user install the correct version of Windows Media Player in case it is not there.

Comment: For system dlls, Thorsten's suggestion is highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference `wmp.dll` directly as it is not a managed library. You could do this instead:

1. Choose a category in the Toolbox.
2. Right-click on that and choose `Choose ToolBox Items`.
3. Open the COM Components Tab.
4. Search for `Windows Media Player`.

This will generate .NET wrappers and add Windows Media Player component to your project where you can manipulate it directly.

Comment: More information can be found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx

Also do more tests for different deployment scenarios to make sure all potential issues are covered.